# Change between two fields on checkbox value

Tags: jquery

I have created a little script to change a variable to two different field ids.

```
var locationSelect = '#shipping_country_code';

function shippingColumn() {
    $(locationSelect).change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val();
        $('.shipping_country_code').val(location);
    });
}
shippingColumn();

$('#order_shipping_same_as_billing').change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
        locationSelect = '#country_code';
    } else {
        locationSelect = '#shipping_country_code';
    }   
    shippingColumn();
});
```

The code works, but there is one issue.
The variable is default set to #shipping_country_code. If the checkbox is changed, the variable is changed to #country_code. So far so good. Then change the checkbox again, and for some reason both fields trigger the on change for the variable locationSelect.

Can anyone see a reason why this would happen in my code?

Comment: Can we see your html markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding a change listener to an element. That listener will still be bound, regardless of which variables you change further down the execution path. You'll need to unbind the listener, <strike>or bind using jQuery's `.one`.</strike>

**Update**. I realize `.one` isn't exactly what you need. It binds a listener to an event that will only fire once and then unregister. You need something that may fire a number of times, and unregister depending on a state. To be able to unregister an event, it is important that the reference is to the very same function (and not just an identical one), so you can't define the event handler inline.

An example that unregisters events may look like this:

```
function selectChange() {
    var location = $(this).val();
    $('.shipping_country_code').val(location);
}

function shippingColumn() {
    $('#shipping_country_code, #country_code').unbind('change', selectChange);
    $(locationSelect).bind('change', selectChange);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6yqfJ/) (I've added an *active* class for clarity).

Now. It is easy to get lost when binding and unbinding listeners. The last thing you want to do (usually) is to accidentally register the same listener twice. I would suggest a different approach, that I think will yield fewer problems down the line, where you bind the event handlers once and for all, at `DOMReady`, that will *always* fire for *both* elements, and then you use the change listener to check your state variable and see if the event should be handled or not.

```
$('#shipping_country_code, #country_code').change(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(locationSelect)) return;
    var location = $(this).val();
    $('.shipping_country_code').val(location);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NHVmw/)

You'll note that for your use case you don't *really* have to use a state variable with this solution; it is almost as easy to evaluate whether the current event should be handled as it happens:

```
$('#shipping_country_code, #country_code').change(function() {
    var sameAsBilling = $('#order_shipping_same_as_billing').is(':checked');
    if((this.id == 'country_code' && !sameAsBilling) ||
       (this.id == 'shipping_country_code' && sameAsBilling)) return;
    var location = $(this).val();
    $('.shipping_country_code').val(location);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/48ybh/)

The logic inside the listener becomes a little bit more complex, but all the logic is contained in one single listener, so that may make the entirety of the code less complex to follow in a larger project.

Comment: Thanks. I have just read up about .one(), can't say I have ever come across it. I am a little unsure how to implement this, as I need the variable change event to be able change multiple times between checkbox change... could you possibly show an example?

Comment: @ccdavies: Yeah, I realize that `.one` was a poor suggestion. I've updated my answer with some better ones.

Comment: An absolutely fantastic explanation! Thank you!!